# file recovery with foremost

Tags: data-recovery, computer-forensics

I have an SD-card from a raspberry pi that has an ext4 partition on it. Due to voltage fluctuations, it crashed so bad that the file system is unmountable. No amount of efsck can repair it. Every superblock is bad, even the backup superblocks!

But with foremost, I found part of the data I needed!

I am looking for text files, javascript files for a project. With foremost, I created a custom js selector in the foremost.conf file. I successfully found multiple copies of the code I wanted.

The bad part is, it is not the whole javascript file. I could only make the header-footer the beginning-end of a function in the file. BUT!

Foremost outputs the files as blocknumber.js files. So I know the block where the data is.

How can I dump the given whole block to a file? Opening that in a text file would show like:
#&#@#&@#@-Gibberish-#@#&@
-Javascript-begins----useful-data-Javascript-ends-
#&#@#&@#@-Gibberish-again-#@#&@

From that, I could extract the needed data!

Thx for Your help!